# What is difference between tail recursive and stack recursive functions?

Tags: functional-programming, tail-recursion

In pure functional languages, say writing factorial function as,

```
fact.0 = 1
fact.n = n*fact.n-1
```

as this function is stack recursive, could anybody explain difference between stack recursive and tell recursive functions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean tail recursive ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is tail-recursion?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33923/what-is-tail-recursion)

Comment: Yes, but i want difference between tail recursive and stack recursive functions.

Comment: it will be  great if anybody give me factorial function with other tail recursion.

Answer (score 3):

The difference between tail recursion and stack recursion (as you call it) is that tail recursive functions can be transformed  into imperative code that will not use the call stack (i.e., essentially a while loop), while with stack recursion, the stack depth is proportional to the recursion depth. This could mean that the program overflows the stack.

Note that "transformation into imperative code" is what takes commonly takes place in code generation, as the output language of compilers is often Assembly, C or some other low level imperative language.

Note that this has nothing to do with functional or even pure functional languages, you have the same problem in every language that supports recursion. It is only that in some functional languages, recursion is the only way of looping.